# npgsql to PostGIS adds ::text, making st_intersects fail

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, postgis, npgsql

I've seen numerous old posts about this but no clear solution.

We use PostGreSQL 9.3 with PostGIS 2; NHibernate 3.2.0-GA with Npgsql 2.1.2.
We have an ASP.NET website witch uses MySQL Spatial and we are now in the progress of switching to PostGIS.
My query that fails is send to NHibernate using this code:

```
    string hql = string.Format("select item from {0} item 
      where NHSP.Intersects(item.Polygon,:boundary) 
      and item.Layer = :layer", typeof(Data.Item).Name);
    IQuery query = CurrentSession.CreateQuery(hql);
    query.SetParameter("boundary", boundary, GeometryType);
    query.SetParameter("layer", layer);
    return query.List<Data.Item>();
```

This should generate a query like this:

```
    select * from fields
    where layer = 'tst'
    and st_intersects(polygon,
    '0103000020000000000100000005000000F[..]4A40');
```

But it generates a query like this:

```
    select * from fields
    where layer = 'tst'
    and st_intersects(polygon,
    '0103000020000000000100000005000000F[..]4A40'::text);
```

Notice the ::text at the end. This results in the following exception:

```
     Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 42725: function st_intersects(geometry, text) is not unique
```

The reason is because the second argument is send as text to PostGIS instead of a geometry.

I've change some code in the NH Spatial library, as suggested elsewhere:
I added these lines to GeometryTypeBase.cs (NHibernate.Spatial)

```
    protected GeometryTypeBase(NullableType nullableType, SqlType sqlTypeOverwrite)
        : this(nullableType)
    {
        this.sqlType = sqlTypeOverwrite;
    }
```

And changed

```
    public PostGisGeometryType()
        : base(NHibernateUtil.StringClob)
    {
    }
```

into

```
    public PostGisGeometryType()
        : base(NHibernateUtil.StringClob, new NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType(System.Data.DbType.Object))
    {
    }
```

in PostGisGeometryType.cs (PostGIS driver)

When I run my application I now get a cast exception on

```
    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        this.nullableType.NullSafeSet(cmd, this.FromGeometry(value), index);
    }
```

also in GeometryTypeBase.cs (NHibernate.Spatial):

```
    System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast System.String into any valid DbType.
```

Any suggestion how to fix this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've kept on searching and altering my search string I've found the answer in https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/issues/201

In NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlTypesHelper.cs

```
    nativeTypeMapping.AddType("text_nonbinary", NpgsqlDbType.Text, DbType.Object, true);
    nativeTypeMapping.AddDbTypeAlias("text_nonbinary", DbType.Object);
```

needs to be changed to

```
    nativeTypeMapping.AddType("unknown", NpgsqlDbType.Text, DbType.Object, true);
    nativeTypeMapping.AddDbTypeAlias("unknown", DbType.Object);
```

And also my earlier fix to PostGisGeometryType needs to be done.
Now I finally can get my geometry data from PostGIS.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for figuring this out. Quite a lot of NHSpatial/PostGis users have ran into this bug. I will create a test case for this, apply your fix and publish new Nuget packages ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for applying my suggestion. I forgot all about it since I posted this almost 2 years ago ;)

Comment: Hi again @paul-meems, if I remember correctly the latest PostGis package on NuGet should incorporate this fix. Can you try it out and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Hi @andrerav currently I'm bound to use an old version of npsql so I cannot test. Soon I hope to upgrade/update our project to the newest versions of available packages like npsql.

Comment: Alright, let me know if you run into problems when you do :) I suspect that I also need to do some work to implement support for NPGSQL 3.